# How to write the validation rule with following criteria

Tags: validation, profile

```
AND( 
($Profile.Name ="France User"), 
OR( 
(OR(Max_Quantity__c < Asked_Quantity_Number__c , 
'Max_Quantity__c'=='Asked_Quantity_Number__c')), 
OR(Max_Quantity__c < BatchQuantity_Number__c , 
'Max_Quantity__c'=='BatchQuantity_Number__c')), 
((OR(Asked_Quantity_Number__c<BatchQuantity_Number__c, 
'Asked_Quantity_Number__c'=='BatchQuantity_Number__c')) 
) 
)
```

`Max_Quantity__c, Asked_Quantity_Number__c, BatchQuantity_Number__c`  are number fields

i need the condition that: `BatchQuantity_Number__c <=Asked_Quantity_Number__c <=  Max_Quantity__c`

The above validation rule is not working, can you suggest to me where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can really simplify this down, you've only got two real constraints, that batch quantity number is less than or equal to the asked quantity, and that the asked quantity is less than or equal to the max. Therefore if the batch is greater than the ask then the first condition would fail, and if the ask was greater than the max then the second would fail.

So you get (unless I've misunderstood your question):

```
AND( 
  ($Profile.Name = "France User"), 
  OR(
    Max_Quantity__c < Asked_Quantity_Number__c,
    Asked_Quantity_Number__c < BatchQuantity_Number__c
  )
)
```

If you use the short cuts for AND() and OR() it's a bit easier to read:

```
($Profile.Name = "France User") && (Max_Quantity__c < Asked_Quantity_Number__c || Asked_Quantity_Number__c < BatchQuantity_Number__c)
```

Comment: one more doubt ,i wrote one validation for unitprice should always be greater than zero in the same visualforce page ,where Max_Quantity__c, Asked_Quantity_Number__c, BatchQuantity_Number__c,unitprice__c fields are there,

Comment: when saving the record with unit price less than zero ,it is showing error that unit price is greater than zero.

Comment: but when i am using another validation which you wrote above ,

Comment: when i am trying to save the record it is not showing error and it is not saving .why it is showing the error?..why it is showing the error in case of validation rule

Comment: with that unit price validation

Comment: What exactly did you specify for the price validation rule? Also if this is a VF page you'll want an `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag in there to show any errors.